# Jest transformer setup for Angular project with IBM Carbon library

Tags: angular, jestjs, carbon-design-system, jest-preset-angular

I'm trying to implement *IBM Carbon library* in angular project.
The implementation is working fine.

But I want to use *Jest* testing platform to run unit tests. Problem is that Jest don't like the way how Carbon *Icon module* is written.

By browsing the web and some forums found out that a **transformer** in *Jest configuration* should be set.

I'm using **jest-preset-angular** library and I set it up as **transform** option in the jest config. But problem is that the error is still popping-up.

I need help for making it work.

Here is the repo where I put a sendbox code.

https://github.com/plachy-jozef/carbon-angular-transformer-issue

The error will be up after running *npm run test:w*.
[image]

Thank you very much for any poking to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There is Github repository which helps you to kick start your Angular project using carbon design system: https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-angular-starter/tree/master

You can find `moduleNameMapper` in `jest.config.ts` file.

```
moduleNameMapper: {
        /**
         * Bypass icon registration error that occurs in JEST
         *
         * In CCA, we import icons from `es` directory... which is bundled as EcmaScript Modules (esm).
         * Jest has experimental support for `esm` as of now. Hence we need to bypass this error
         * by pointing to the common js equivalent.
         *
         */
        "^@carbon/icons/es/(.*)$": "@carbon/icons/lib/$1.js",
    }
```